# SQL logic error only when querying on Android

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk

I am working on a C++ Android NDK project that relies on a SQLite3 database as a data repository. The database has three tables; column counts are 6, 8, and 6; row counts are 240, ~12.5 million, and ~4 million.

The SQLite driver is being compiled, unmodified, directly into my native library from the SQLite3 amalgamation source code, version 3.19.3.

My problem is that when running the native library, the database query results in *"SQL logic error or missing database"* . I know the database is where I expect, and is accessible. If I execute the same query against the same database in a desktop environment (rather than on the mobile device), I see the expected results. Furthermore, if I execute the same query on the mobile device using a database housing a subset of the data in the repository (~300 total records), I see the expected results.

Any ideas?

For reference, here is the query I'm using:

```
WITH 
    weather_distance AS 
        (SELECT  latitude, longitude, temperature, humidity, time, (ABS((latitude - $lat)) + ABS((longitude - $lon))) AS distance FROM Weather WHERE time BETWEEN $start AND $end), 
    min_weather_distance AS 
        (SELECT latitude, longitude, temperature, humidity, time FROM weather_distance WHERE distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM weather_distance)), 
    solar_distance AS 
        (SELECT  latitude, longitude, ghi, (time - 1800) AS time, (ABS((latitude - $lat)) + ABS((longitude - $lon))) AS distance FROM SolarData WHERE time BETWEEN $start AND $end), 
    min_solar_distance AS 
        (SELECT  latitude, longitude, ghi, time FROM solar_distance WHERE distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM solar_distance)) 
SELECT s.time, s.ghi, w.temperature, w.humidity FROM min_weather_distance w INNER JOIN min_solar_distance s ON w.time = s.time ORDER BY s.time ASC
```

and the code (C++) I'm using to make the query:

```
const char* getEnvQuery =
        "WITH "
            "weather_distance AS "
                "(SELECT  latitude, longitude, temperature, humidity, time, (ABS((latitude - $lat)) + ABS((longitude - $lon))) AS distance FROM Weather WHERE time BETWEEN $start AND $end), "
            "min_weather_distance AS "
                "(SELECT latitude, longitude, temperature, humidity, time FROM weather_distance WHERE distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM weather_distance)), "
            "solar_distance AS "
                "(SELECT  latitude, longitude, ghi, (time - 1800) AS time, (ABS((latitude - $lat)) + ABS((longitude - $lon))) AS distance FROM SolarData WHERE time BETWEEN $start AND $end), "
            "min_solar_distance AS (SELECT  latitude, longitude, ghi, time FROM solar_distance WHERE distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM solar_distance)) "
        "SELECT s.time, s.ghi, w.temperature, w.humidity FROM min_weather_distance w INNER JOIN min_solar_distance s ON w.time = s.time ORDER BY s.time ASC;\0";

sqlite3_stmt* getEnvStmt;
prepareSqlStatement(getEnvQuery, &getEnvStmt, envdbhandle, "Error preparing SQL statement to retrieve environmental data. SQLite return code: ");
sqlite3_bind_double(getEnvStmt, 1, iter->latitude); //iter is defined above quoted code
sqlite3_bind_double(getEnvStmt, 2, iter->longitude);
sqlite3_bind_double(getEnvStmt, 3, iter->startTime);
sqlite3_bind_double(getEnvStmt, 4, iter->endTime);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SPP/getEnvironment", "Bound parameters: lat=%f, lon=%f, start=%ld, end=%ld", iter->latitude, iter->longitude, iter->startTime, iter->endTime);
int rc = sqlite3_step(getEnvStmt);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SPP/getEnvironment", "step(getEnvStmt) = %d", rc);
int errCode = sqlite3_extended_errcode(envdbhandle);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SPP/getEnvironment", "Most recent SQLITE error code: %s. Message: %s", sqlite3_errstr(errCode), sqlite3_errmsg(envdbhandle));
while(rc == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    EnvironmentDatum envData;
    int dbTime = sqlite3_column_int(getEnvStmt, 0);
    envData.UnixTime = timeconvert::secondsOfYearToUNIXTime(dbTime, year);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SPP/getEnvironment", "EnvironmentDatum dbTime=%d, UnixTime=%f", dbTime, envData.UnixTime);
    envData.GHI = sqlite3_column_double(getEnvStmt, 1);
    envData.Temperature = sqlite3_column_double(getEnvStmt, 2);
    envData.Humidity = sqlite3_column_double(getEnvStmt, 3);
    envCollection.push_back(envData);
    rc = sqlite3_step(getEnvStmt);
}
sqlite3_finalize(getEnvStmt);
```

Important debugging info:

```
sqlite3_stmt* verQueryStmt;
prepareSqlStatement("select sqlite_version();\0", &verQueryStmt, envdbhandle, "Error getting driver version. Error code:");
sqlite3_step(verQueryStmt);
std::string sqliteVersion = parseSqliteStringColumn(verQueryStmt, 0);
sqlite3_finalize(verQueryStmt);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SPP/buildScenario", "sqlite version=%s", sqliteVersion.c_str()); // outputs "sqlite version=3.19.3"
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SPP/buildScenario", "env db readability=%s", (sqlite3_db_readonly(envdbhandle, "main") == 1 ? "READONLY" : (sqlite3_db_readonly(envdbhandle, "main") == 0 ? "READ/WRITE" : "NOT CONNECTED"))); // outputs "READ/WRITE"
```

Per request, here is prepareStatement:

```
static int prepareSqlStatement(const char* query, sqlite3_stmt** statement, sqlite3* db, const char* failMsg)
{
    int returnCode = sqlite3_prepare(db, query, -1, statement, NULL);
    if(returnCode != SQLITE_OK || statement == NULL)
    {
        int errCode = sqlite3_extended_errcode(dbhandle);
        std::cout << "Most recent SQLITE error code: " << sqlite3_errstr(errCode) << ". Message: " << sqlite3_errmsg(dbhandle) << std::endl;
        reportError(failMsg, -1 * returnCode);
    }
    return returnCode;
}
```

And in anticipation, here is reportError:

```
static void reportError(const char* message, int errorCode)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << message << errorCode;
    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
}
```

Comment: Call `sqlite3_errmsg()`.

Comment: @CL that's how I got the "SQL logic error or missing database" message.

Comment: There is no such call in the code you've shown.

Comment: You're correct. The code as posted was from a previous iteration of debugging. I've updated the code to show the call.

Comment: What does `prepareSqlStatement()` do?

Comment: It wraps a call to sqlite3_prepare in some error handling. It works fine every other place in the code that I use it.

Comment: Show `prepareSqlStatement()`.

Comment: I have added the code for prepareSqlStatement.

Comment: Show the actual log message.

Comment: 06-27 15:08:01.740 24490-24530/mil.army.cpi.power.soldierpowerplanning D/SPP/getEnvironment: step(getEnvStmt) = 1

    06-27 15:08:01.740 24490-24530/mil.army.cpi.power.soldierpowerplanning D/SPP/getEnvironment: **Most recent SQLITE error code: SQL logic error or missing database. Message: SQL logic error or missing database**

I guess you didn't believe me when I said that was the error I'm seeing?

Comment: Sorry, now I do. As far as I am aware, it should not be possible for this error code to occur without a custom error message. Please add logging of the [error log](http://www.sqlite.org/errlog.html).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this utility. The message I get from that is **(6410) statement aborts at 48: [WITH weather_distance AS (SELECT  latitude, longitude, temperature, humidity, time, (ABS((latitude - $lat)) + ABS((longitude - $lon))) AS distance FROM Weather WHERE time BETWEEN $star**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When intermediate results of the query become too large, the database must swap out some data into a temporary file.

6410 is `SQLITE_IOERR_GETTEMPPATH`, which means that none of the [temporary file storage locations](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temporary_file_storage_locations) are accessible.

Android doesn't have any of the default Unix paths. The built-in database framework compiles its copy of the SQLite library with [SQLITE_TEMP_STORE](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#temp_store) = 3. If you want to get actual temporary files instead, you should put them into whatever directory is returned by [`Context.getCacheDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()); this would require setting the SQLITE_TMPDIR environment variable.

Comment: Finally got around to looking into it again. The intermediate queries are big enough that they don't fit in memory, so I ended up changing the temporary file store by setting **PRAGMA temp_store_directory** to */mnt/sdcard* and that worked. I think I need to rework my query though, 40 minutes is a bit long to wait for a mobile app :-)